# How to properly fire a callback after an animation and ajax calls have been successfully completed?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, callback

Well I have a AJAX calls being performed while I animate some content.

I want to fire a callback after both are finished successfully?

Any idea?

**EDIT:** fix typos in the title

Comment: Can you chain the two events? ie. call the animation in the AJAX callback, and then use the animation callback for your next function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Here's some rough code on how it would work.

```
function doAjax(){
   return $.get('foo.htm'); // or $.ajax, $.getJSON.....etc 
}

function doAnimation(){
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   $("div").fadeIn(800).delay(1200).fadeOut(300, dfd.resolve);
   return dfd.promise();
}

$.when( doAjax(), doAnimation() )
 .then(function(){
    console.log( 'I fire once BOTH have completed!' );
 })
 .fail(function(){
    console.log( 'I fire if one or more requests failed.' );
 });
```

Some references:

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

As per some comments i checked to make sure both animation and ajax calls execute in parallel and as expected, they do. http://jsfiddle.net/Gdqfp/4/

Comment: Thank you! Smart jQuerying :)

Comment: Ah... There's a slight problem. This fires even if the animation is stopped prematurely with `.stop`. I think we should create a new deferred object and `.resolve` it in `fadeOut` callback. I'll try to edit your answer.
*EDIT*: Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/RwXk2/

Comment: Shouldn't the animation result be marked as `fail` if stopped manually?

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of this, where both success functions check that the other has finished using a global variable?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png',
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    window.waitingforajax = true
  },
  success: function( ) {
    window.waitingforajax = false;
    if (window.waitingforanimation) {
      myCallback();
    }   
  }
});

window.waitingforanimation = true;
$('#book').animate({
  opacity: 0.25,
  left: '+=50',
  height: 'toggle'
}, 5000, function() {
  window.waitingforanimation= false;
  if (window.waitingforajax) {
    myCallback();
  }  
});
```

Comment: Yes this works but only on a small scale. I might have several AJAX calls...or multiple animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jQuery.when( animation, ajax ).then( success );
```

But that wont execute the methods at the same time. Another option is something like:

```
var stops = 2,
    check = function() {
        if (!--stops) {
            alert('ready!');
        }
    };

$('#elem').animate({opacity:0}, check);
$.ajax('domain.com', check);
```

EDIT: appears that I was wrong. Try the $.when.then method, much cleaner!

Comment: I don't understand. Why is not firing them in parallel?

Comment: @antitoxic see my edit, I think jQuery actually DO fire them simultaneously using when/then. What are your tests showing?